# Why my question got deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Just now I posted a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75905/why-salesman-not-accepting-the-ticket-without-even-looking-at-it) regarding **The Family Man**, it got removed.

I am new user here. I solved my question by clicking the green tick.

I am just learning about it.

Is that mistake I did now? That is why you deleted my question.

Comment: what was your question?

Comment: @Vishwa i believe it was [this one](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75905/why-salesman-not-accepting-the-ticket-without-even-looking-at-it) now deleted

Comment: if it was bad question, it's possible it get deleted. a lot of downvotes, not enough information, not meeting the community standard and many reasons. you can read the reasons in here,     https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions

Answer (score 14):

The question was deleted by the system because your account was deleted by a moderator, because it was flagged as likely to be a user that we are having trouble with.  This user is creating multiple short lived accounts, one per movie they watch, to ask 1-3 questions.

Please see the following question and answer on Meta-Stackexchange

[Why did my 150+ reputation account at Movies Stack Exchange get suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297480/why-did-my-150-reputation-account-at-movies-stack-exchange-get-suspended/297495#297495)

You may ask, "what is the problem with this behavior?".  The problem is that:

1. we've seen some sockpuppet behavior from these accounts in the past, and
2. many of the questions have attracted downvotes and therefore the user is avoiding automated question bans.

We don't have a generic problem with just creating multiple accounts. Ideally we would avoid that and the whole intent of building reputation and privileges is predicated on using the same account.  However by creating literally more than 50 accounts over the last few months the user has been avoiding automated question ban and isn't responding to attempts by moderators to communicate and discuss this.

I'm not saying this is you - I'm saying that this is why the account was flagged and deleted.